# Как сделать, чтобы при раскрытии блока все нижние блоки сдвигались вниз?

Tags: html, bootstrap

Я использую Bootstrap 3. Страница должна быть адаптивной, нужно, чтобы это работало и в том случае, когда будет две колонки в строке. При раскрытии третьей колонки работает как надо.

[image: proper]

[image: not proper]

```js
var main = function() {
  $(".panel-heading").click(function() {
    $(this).siblings(".panel-body").slideToggle(240);
  });

}
$(document).ready(main);
```

```css
.panel-container {
  padding: 5px !important;
}
.container {
  height: 100%;
}
.panel-body {
  display: none;
}
.panel-heading:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel-container col-lg-4">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      Head panel
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      Content...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вставляйте через каждые 3 (2) колонки блок с `.clearfix`, по такому принципу:

```
<div class="panel-container col-sm-6 col-lg-4">...</div> <!-- Блок #1 -->
<div class="panel-container col-sm-6 col-lg-4">...</div> <!-- Блок #2 -->
<div class="clearfix visible-sm visible-md">...</div>    <!-- Начинаем новый ряд для блоков по 2 в ряд -->
<div class="panel-container col-sm-6 col-lg-4">...</div> <!-- Блок #3 -->
<div class="clearfix visible-lg"></div>                  <!-- Начинаем новый ряд для блоков по 3 в ряд -->
<div class="panel-container col-sm-6 col-lg-4">...</div> <!-- Блок #4 -->
<div class="clearfix visible-sm visible-md">...</div>    <!-- Начинаем новый ряд для блоков по 2 в ряд -->
<div class="panel-container col-sm-6 col-lg-4">...</div> <!-- Блок #5 -->
<div class="panel-container col-sm-6 col-lg-4">...</div> <!-- Блок #6 -->
<div class="clearfix visible-sm visible-md">...</div>    <!-- Начинаем новый ряд для блоков по 2 в ряд -->
<div class="clearfix visible-lg"></div>                  <!-- Начинаем новый ряд для блоков по 3 в ряд -->
```

- На `xs` экранах - блоки будут по одному в ряд;
- На `sm` - по два, за счет `.col-sm-6`;
- На `md` - по два, `.col-md-x` не указан, значит так же, как на экране предыдущего размера;
- На `lg` - по три, за счет `.col-lg-4`.

За счет `.visible-xx` - регулируете видимость (и фактическую действенность) блоков `.clearfix` для разных размеров экранов.